# How to find the fortran compiler used by the existing source code?

Tags: fortran, executable

This question might be very naive. So please bear with me here.
I am trying to run some old Fortran code of my project team in ubuntu 14.04. Last compilation of this code was at 2006. All the object files and executable files from the last run are still available.

I am trying to run this code to reproduce everything but I don't know the fortran compiler they used. So, I am using fort77 and gfortran-4.8.

Is there any ways to figure out the fortran compiler originally used in 2006 from the existing fortran source file and object files?

Comment: Open the executable in in a binary editor and look for human-readable strings.

Comment: @VladimirF, I opened the executable using Sublime and there is no human-readable string. Its full of numbers and characters in a 8 column format like this `0908 6800 0000 00e9 e0ff ffff ff25 1475` `0908 6828 0000 00e9 90ff ffff ff25 2875`. Is there any other way?

Comment: You have to set the view to bytes as characters. I do not know Sublime, I use Okteta. Or use the `strings` command https://serverfault.com/questions/51477/linux-command-to-find-strings-in-binary-or-non-ascii-file

Comment: I answered your actual question. However, I do not think that knowing the previous compiler is terribly useful. You should strive to make your code compilable by current standard-conforming compilers.

Comment: @VladimirF, Sorry for the late reply as I was going through the strings in the executable. Some of the useful lines are `GCC: (GNU) 3.2 20020903 (Red Hat Linux 8.0 3.2-7)` `GCC: (GNU) egcs-2.91.66 19990314/Linux (egcs-1.1.2 release)` `/usr/lib/gcc-lib/i386-redhat-linux/3.2/include/stddef.h`. From this I guess they used gfortran from GCC version 3.2 on Red Hat Linux 8.0 with 32 bit. Please correct me if I am wrong..

Comment: There was no gfortran in GCC 3. Only g77. RedHat 8 is an extremely old Linux and g77 is a completely obsolete compiler that was superseded by gfortran.

Comment: @VladimirF, So installing g77 and RedHat 8 is a dead end and more pain. THerefore, using the already installed compilers such as fort77 and gfortran-4.8 in my ubuntu 14.04 (64 bit), I will try to start the debugging tomorrow. Thanks again. Chat you tomorrow.

Comment: @MohammedNiyasdeen: Well, Ubuntu 14.04 is also pretty old by now, and receives no security updates etc. Might be a good idea to update that as well (and you'll get a newer and better version of gfortran as well).

Comment: @janneb, I have other in-house source codes and application up and running in ubuntu14.04. Thanks for your suggestion and I will consider it in the future.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `strings` command to see printable strings in the executable. For, example, I get

```
> strings a.out 
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
__gmon_start__
_gfortran_transfer_real_write
_gfortran_st_write_done
_gfortran_transfer_character_write
_gfortran_set_options
_gfortran_st_write
_gfortran_set_args
__libc_start_main
libgfortran.so.4
libm.so.6
libgcc_s.so.1
libquadmath.so.0
libc.so.6
GLIBC_2.2.5
GFORTRAN_7
=1       
AWAVI
AUATL
[]A\A]A^A_
format2.f90
(A,/, A,/, ((F5.2, F5.2)))12
;*3$"
GCC: (SUSE Linux) 7.5.0
_`      @
../sysdeps/x86_64
start.S
.B#>M$$uv
init.c
../sysdeps/x86_64
crti.S
Lu=/
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/include
elf-init.c
stddef.h
../sysdeps/x86_64
crtn.S
../sysdeps/x86_64/start.S
/home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/glibc-2.31/csu
GNU AS 2.35.1
GNU C11 7.5.0 -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g -g -O2 -std=gnu11 -fgnu89-inline -fmessage-length=0 -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fmerge-all-constants -frounding-math -fstack-protector-strong -fmath-errno -fno-stack-protector -ftls-model=initial-exec -fPIE
_IO_stdin_used
static-reloc.c
../sysdeps/x86_64/crti.S
long long int
size_t
__init_array_start
envp
__fini_array_start
elf-init.c
long unsigned int
__libc_csu_fini
__fini_array_end
GNU C11 7.5.0 -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g -g -O2 -std=gnu11 -fgnu89-inline -fmessage-length=0 -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fmerge-all-constants -frounding-math -fstack-protector-strong -fmath-errno -fno-stack-protector -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -ftls-model=initial-exec
char
__preinit_array_start
argc
size
__libc_csu_init
argv
long double
__preinit_array_end
__init_array_end
../sysdeps/x86_64/crtn.S
static-reloc.c
crtstuff.c
deregister_tm_clones
__do_global_dtors_aux
completed.6999
__do_global_dtors_aux_fini_array_entry
frame_dummy
__frame_dummy_init_array_entry
format2.f90
MAIN__
options.1.3517
elf-init.c
__FRAME_END__
__GNU_EH_FRAME_HDR
_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
__init_array_end
__init_array_start
_DYNAMIC
__libc_csu_fini
_gfortran_set_args@GFORTRAN_7
__gmon_start__
_gfortran_st_write@GFORTRAN_7
__libc_start_main@GLIBC_2.2.5
_IO_stdin_used
__data_start
_gfortran_st_write_done@GFORTRAN_7
__TMC_END__
__dso_handle
_gfortran_set_options@GFORTRAN_7
__libc_csu_init
_gfortran_transfer_character_write@GFORTRAN_7
__bss_start
_gfortran_transfer_real_write@GFORTRAN_7
_edata
main
.symtab
.strtab
.shstrtab
.interp
.note.gnu.build-id
.note.ABI-tag
.gnu.hash
.dynsym
.dynstr
.gnu.version
.gnu.version_r
.rela.dyn
.rela.plt
.init
.text
.fini
.rodata
.eh_frame_hdr
.eh_frame
.init_array
.fini_array
.dynamic
.got
.got.plt
.data
.bss
.comment
.debug_aranges
.debug_info
.debug_abbrev
.debug_line
.debug_str
.debug_loc
.debug_ranges
```

The key is in `GCC: (SUSE Linux) 7.5.0`. It is gfortran from GCC version 7.5.0 on SUSE Linux.

However, it is not always that simple.

In this case

```
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
__gmon_start__
_gfortran_transfer_integer_write
_gfortran_st_write_done
_gfortran_transfer_character_write
_gfortran_set_options
_gfortran_st_write
_gfortran_set_args
__libc_start_main
libgfortran.so.5
libm.so.6
libgcc_s.so.1
libquadmath.so.0
libc.so.6
GFORTRAN_8
GLIBC_2.2.5
=-       
AWAVI
AUATL
[]A\A]A^A_
clear.f90
no(A,2i15,A5)
;*3$"
GCC: (SUSE Linux) 7.5.0
GCC: (SUSE Linux) 11.2.1 20220103 [revision d4a1d3c4b377f1d4acb34fe1b55b5088a3f293f6]
_0      @
../sysdeps/x86_64
start.S
.B#>M$
init.c
../sysdeps/x86_64
crti.S
Lu=/
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/include
elf-init.c
stddef.h
../sysdeps/x86_64
crtn.S
../sysdeps/x86_64/start.S
/home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/glibc-2.26/csu
GNU AS 2.37
long unsigned int
short int
_IO_stdin_used
unsigned char
GNU C11 7.5.0 -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g -O2 -std=gnu11 -fgnu89-inline -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fmerge-all-constants -fmessage-length=0 -frounding-math -fstack-clash-protection -fstack-protector-strong -funwind-tables -fno-stack-protector -ftls-model=initial-exec -fPIE
short unsigned int
../sysdeps/x86_64/crti.S
long long int
__init_array_start
size_t
envp
__fini_array_start
elf-init.c
GNU C11 7.5.0 -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g -O2 -std=gnu11 -fgnu89-inline -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fmerge-all-constants -fmessage-length=0 -frounding-math -fstack-clash-protection -fstack-protector-strong -funwind-tables -fno-stack-protector -fPIC -ftls-model=initial-exec
__libc_csu_fini
__fini_array_end
__preinit_array_start
argc
size
__libc_csu_init
argv
long double
__preinit_array_end
__init_array_end
../sysdeps/x86_64/crtn.S
crtstuff.c
deregister_tm_clones
__do_global_dtors_aux
completed.0
__do_global_dtors_aux_fini_array_entry
frame_dummy
__frame_dummy_init_array_entry
clear.f90
MAIN__
options.1.0
elf-init.c
__FRAME_END__
__GNU_EH_FRAME_HDR
_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
__init_array_end
__init_array_start
_DYNAMIC
__libc_csu_fini
__gmon_start__
__libc_start_main@GLIBC_2.2.5
_gfortran_transfer_integer_write@GFORTRAN_8
_IO_stdin_used
__data_start
_gfortran_transfer_character_write@GFORTRAN_8
__TMC_END__
__dso_handle
__libc_csu_init
_gfortran_st_write_done@GFORTRAN_8
__bss_start
_gfortran_set_options@GFORTRAN_8
_gfortran_set_args@GFORTRAN_8
_edata
_gfortran_st_write@GFORTRAN_8
main
.symtab
.strtab
.shstrtab
.interp
.note.gnu.build-id
.note.ABI-tag
.gnu.hash
.dynsym
.dynstr
.gnu.version
.gnu.version_r
.rela.dyn
.rela.plt
.init
.text
.fini
.rodata
.eh_frame_hdr
.eh_frame
.init_array
.fini_array
.dynamic
.got
.got.plt
.data
.bss
.comment
.debug_aranges
.debug_info
.debug_abbrev
.debug_line
.debug_str
.debug_loc
.debug_ranges
```

you have two such strings

```
GCC: (SUSE Linux) 7.5.0
GCC: (SUSE Linux) 11.2.1 20220103 [revision d4a1d3c4b377f1d4acb34fe1b55b5088a3f293f6]
```

The actual compiler is gfortran 11.2.1, the 7.5.0 was used to compile the operating system and various libraries.

The version of libgfortran is also strongly tied to the compiler version used.

---

For other compilers the version might not be present at all, you will have to deduce the type of compiler from the individual symbols referenced or various error messages or similar strings.

For example the list of strings from the executable generated by the latest Intel Fortran (ifort) is too long to be pasted here.

One trap is, that it does contain also

```
GCC_3.0
GCC_3.3
GCC: (SUSE Linux) 7.5.0
```

but these again refer to the operating system and various libraries. Other strings clearly point to Intel Fortran though:

```
> grep -in Intel  intel.strings    
3172:for_diags_intel.c
3179:@(#)Intel Fortran RTL Message Catalog      V20.0-001 Jan 10 2019
3291:unresolved contention for Intel Fortran RTL global resource
3319:Intel Pentium fdiv flaw detected, please update the processor
3392:Intel(r) Visual Fortran run-time error 
3634:File-path is longer than Intel(r) Fortran limit of 4096
4113:Intel(R) Pentium(R) M and compatible Intel processors
4114:Intel(R) processors with Swing New Instructions support
4115:Intel(R) processors with MOVBE instructions support
4124:Intel(R) Core(TM) Duo processors and compatible Intel processors with supplemental Streaming SIMD Extensions 3 (SSSE3) instruction support
4125:Intel(R) Pentium(R) 4 and compatible Intel processors with Intel(R) Streaming SIMD Extensions 3 (Intel(R) SSE3) instruction support
4126:Intel(R) Pentium(R) 4 and compatible Intel processors. Enables new optimizations in addition to Intel processor-specific optimizations
4127:Intel(R) processors with SSE4.2 and POPCNT instructions support
4128:Please verify that both the operating system and the processor support Intel(R) AVX.
4129:Please verify that both the operating system and the processor support Intel(R) AVX, F16C and RDRAND instructions.
4130:Please verify that both the operating system and the processor support Intel(R) AVX2, BMI, LZCNT, HLE, RTM and FMA instructions.
4131:Please verify that both the operating system and the processor support Intel(R) %s instructions.
4132:Please verify that your application was built with compatible Intel(R) libirc library
4133:Use of incompatible or internally inconsistent Intel(R) libirc library
4240:INTEL_ISA_DISABLE
4241:__INTEL_LIBIRC_DEBUG
4386:for_diags_intel.c
4397:for_msgtab_intel
4550:_intel_get_fast_memcpy_impl.A
4551:_intel_get_fast_memcpy_impl.J
4552:_intel_get_fast_memcpy_impl.M
4553:_intel_get_fast_memcpy_impl.P
4554:_intel_get_fast_memcpy_impl.V
4555:_intel_get_fast_memcpy_impl.Z
```

The version is not seen there in a human-readable form (as far as I can see).